# how to insert a data into table with a key already defined

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using Nhibernate in my project. I had a table which had a primary key whose Identity specification was set to true, It was generating auto increment value. this is working fine.
This was happening automatically working fine

Now I want that I should send the Id key from the code a and insert that key into database. like guid, but when I do this it is giving me exception

```
 NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: 
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'User_Id', table 'tablename'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

The statement has been terminated.

```
 Id(x => x.userId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("User_Id");
```

Comment: Post your entity mapping code, especially the id of it.

Answer (score 0):

I do expect, that you want to send a key from code, because the IDENTITY generator on your table is not used. If this is the case, just change your mapping from `Identity` into `Assigned`

```
Id(x => x.userId)
  .GeneratedBy
    .Assigned()
  .Column("User_Id");
```

From that moment, NHibernate will send the INSERT statement with the GUID value you've already set in the code. And this will solve the `...Cannot insert the value NULL...` problem

See more here https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping, section **Id**